# Complex Square root bound

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, inequality

Under what conditions on $a, b$ and the branch cut of the square root does the following hold:
$$
|\sqrt{a + b} - \sqrt{a} | \leq C \frac{|b|}{\sqrt{|a| + |b|}}
$$
for a universal constant $C > 0$.  This seems to be true in the real case, but I'm not familiar enough with the subtleties in the complex plane to generalize this.

Comment: The branch cut choice depends only on where $a$ and $b$ lie in the plane - we can always choose some line so that we don't get issues with the argument jumping by $\pi.$ With that aside, I'm not sure whether there is any way to make this work in general for a $C$ independent of $a$ and $b. $ I'll play around with it when I get a free moment and get back to you.